# Can I require a ruby file so that it becomes a method?

Tags: ruby, require

I have a third-party Ruby file that performs some initialization during start up. The file is in `config/initializers` and it's `required` by *Rails Magic* (although I am using Rails, this is a generic Ruby question).

I want to defer the third-party file's execution so that I can perform it when required under program control, on-demand, and potentially more than once.

I've moved the file out of the initializers area so that it isn't auto-loaded by Rails. I've then defined a method like this:

```
def initialize_thing
  require 'path/to/initializer'
end
```

The effect I was hoping for was that the contents of the file becomes the body of the method but this doesn't happen. Instead, the contends of the file are executed when the require is performed on the first invocation of the method.

I can't modify the file becuase it's supplied by a third party.

The effect that I am looking for is the same as if I just paste the third-pary file's conent directly into my method definition so that it's content isn't executed until, and is executed whenever, the method is called.

**Is there a Ruby way to just include the contents of one file in another without executing it ?**

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a Ruby way to just include the contents of one file in another without executing it ?

What `require` does it to load the file content and evaluate it as Ruby. If what you need is to just read the file without evaluate it, then simply use `File.read`.

If, instead, you want to require a file just at some point, then placing the require inside a method and call the method will just work.

```
# a.rb
puts "Second"

# b.rb
def execute!
  require_relative 'a'
end
puts "First"
execute!

# ruby b.rb
First
Second
```

If it doesn't work, it means something is requiring that file in your system before you do it.

To be honest, this seems a kind of hack to me. The order your files are loaded should not be that relevant.

Comment: Repeat the last line, `execute!`, in `b.rb` so it's called twice. The word `Second` is only output once. It should output twice.

Comment: If you want to execute it twice, then use `load` rather than `require`.

Comment: that's what I am doing now. I thought it seemed wrong, like it's going to the pain of reading the loaded file every time the method is called. I was hoping to avoid that...

Comment: You can read the file separately using `File.read`, store it in memory, then call `eval`. But it seems an unnecessary effort to me as the file will continue to keep memory allocation forever with no reason at all.

Comment: so there's no way to effectively do what would happen if replaced the `require` line with a paste of `a.rb` and had just the one file ?

Answer (score 0):

`require` will only reads and evaluates the file the first time you call it - if you want to read and evaluate it each and every time you need to use `load` instead. See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-load

Comment: That's what I've done. However doesn't this incur the file overhead on each method call? Is there a way to avoid that (apart from using an editor to paste one file into another) ?